# versions in elixir dependencies

Tags: dependencies, elixir, package, versioning

What is the difference between declaring a dependency to a package using this syntax: "==1.2.3" (which I understand, it is clearly explained in the [spec](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Version.html)), and just "1.2.3" (which I also see being used, but it is not explained in the script) ? Is this like a soft constraint, that gives the package manager some freedom to resolve to another version?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

A dependency might by specified as:

- `"== 1.2.3"` effectively the same as `"1.2.3"`, meaning “exactly this version”
- `">= 1.2.3"`, meaning “any version greater or equal that that, including major versions updates”
- `"<= 1.2.3"`, meaning “any version that is not greater that that”
- `"~> 1.2.3"`, meaning “same major version, same minor version with any subversion greater or equal than `3`”
- `"~> 1.2"`, meaning “same major version, with any minor version greater or equal than `2`”

The syntax `"~> 1"` is disallowed, because it’s effectively the same as `">= 1.0.0"`.

So, to have some flexibility people usually do `"~> 1.2.3"` or `"~> 1.2"` if they trust the package using proper semantic versioning. `">= 1.2.3"` is not advised because even with semantic versioning major versions might contain breaking changes.

Answer (score 3):

I believe "1.2.3" is equal to "==1.2.3", which I have never seen been used. But I can't support it with reference unfortunately. But it always behaves like exact match.

**UPDATE** Yup, look here:
https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/f47792547b72ee3043da7205a50e4a1fca2a93dd/lib/elixir/test/elixir/version_test.exs#L52

Comment: thanks for the link, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Version documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Version.html#module-requirements). What you're talking about is a **requirement**.

Version:

> In a nutshell, a version is represented by three numbers

Requirement:

> Requirements allow you to specify which versions of a given dependency you are willing to work against. Requirements support common operators like `>=`, `<=`, `>`, `==`, and friends that work as one would expect

Neither the `Version` documentation nor the [mix documentation](https://hex.pm/docs/usage) say anything about specifying the version number (without an operator) directly as a requirement, so that's probably non-standard practice and best avoided.

Requirements are usually specified with the `~>` operator because that specifies that a version with a higher least-sigificant digit can be used. For example `~> 1.1.0` would allow `1.1.1`, `1.1.2` etc. to be used, but not `1.2.0`. There is a [useful table in the official documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Version.html#module-requirements).

Comment: thanks, those seem to occur in the wild, I came across this in the https://libraries.io/ data sets